# Data returned from fetch request is not what is expected

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am calling some data from my API to the front end.

The call from my front end looks something like:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('Mix') == null){
        const myApi = await fetch('thisSite.io/deetz', { credentials: 'same-origin' })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        const my = await myApi.json;
        console.log(myApi.json, 'kjasdlaj');
}
```

The response in the console is 
`function json() kjasdlaj`

Although when I send a request on my browser to thisSite.io/deetz I get a JSON response giving me something like

```
0
  Name        Jake
  Occupation  Engineer
1
  Name        Mike
  Occupation  Kite Fyler
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong. I have been using this format of fetch for my other code and that seems to work fine.

I can post a minimum reproducible sample also, but since it is a bit lengthy and I guess something is wrong in my code here because it my fetching works correctly elsewhere I am just posting the code I feel there is an issue.

If someone still wants a minimum please tell me.

Comment: That response does not look anything like JSON to me... is that the raw text of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute `json`. So replace `const my = await myApi.json` with `const my = await myApi.json()`.

Next you need to `console.log` `my`, not `myApi.json`. So do this:

```
const my = await myApi.json();
console.log(my, 'kjasdlaj');
```

Comment: Aaaah. OMG. Can't believe I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

A fetch response's `.json` property is an asyncronous function which returns the response's body as a JavaScript object, assuming the response was a JSON string. It is not an object or property to be accessed.

Instead, you probably want this:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('Mix') == null) {
  const responseObject = 
    await fetch('thisSite.io/deetz', { credentials: 'same-origin' })
      .then(res => res.json());
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  console.log(responseObject, 'kjasdlaj');
}
```

This will log the response as an object, allowing you to access properties.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't executing the function.  You're passing it the reference to the function itself.  You need to call `await myApi.json()`, not `await myApi.json`.  You should also log the variable `my`, and not `myApi.json`.